# How does an absolute phrase function?

Tags: phrases, phrase-usage

How does an absolute phrase grammatical function in a sentence?

Does it act as **noun, adjective or adverb?**

Is the entire absolute phrase used as adverb?

Comment: It's none of those. Please see my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Absolute clauses are adjuncts that function as supplements, loosely attached elements set off by intonation and (usually) by punctuation.

> [*His hands gripping the door*]*, he shouted out for help.*

In this example the bracketed supplement qualifies as an absolute construction because it has a subject, and is subordinate in form but has no syntactic link to the main clause ("He shouted out for help").

Thus, its category is non-finite clause and its function is adjunct.

Note that supplements are not modifiers; rather, they refer to a semantic 'anchor', in this case "he".